# Issue running Flutter on Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and i am trying to compile and run a code from a vendor, but I get the error below.

i know its a configuration error but i cant figure it out.

can anyone help out?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/E:/flutter_windows_2.8.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/flutter_windows_2.8.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:16:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/flutter_windows_2.8.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:11:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\flutter_windows_2.8.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'E:\flutter_windows_2.8.0-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10m 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you try with `flutter clean`, also try  with `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

upgraded to Flutter 2.10.0 stable, and it compiled.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add this to your pubspec.yaml and you should be just fine

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
```